# Display jQuery-ui dialog based on the argument within onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a set of links which comes from a PHP loop and each link has a `onclick()` function which contains a number as the argument.

```
echo '<a href="#" id="'.$id.'" onclick="openModel('.$id.')">'.$name.'</a>';
```

So, when the user clicked on the link, I want a jQuery-ui Dialog to popup and display the information relevant to the particular link.

The information is in the DB and they will be queried according to the `$id` I', passing in the `onclick` function.

This is the code for opening the jQuery dialog

```
function openModel(id){
    var dialog, form;

        dialog = jQuery( "#dialog-form-text-box" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          height: 300,
          width: 350,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            "Done": function() {
              dialog.dialog( "close" );
            }
          },

        });

    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });

   dialog.dialog( "open" );
}
```

This is the code for what's inside the jQuery dialog

```
<div id="dialog-form-text-box" title="Text Box">
    <p id="mini-title"></p>
  <form>
      <input type="text" name="textbox-title" id="textbox-title" value="<?php echo $parsedArr[0]['content']['title'] ?>" placeholder="Title"> <br> <br>
      <textarea name="textbox-desc" id="textbox-desc" placeholder="Description"><?php echo $parsedArr[4]['content']['content'] ?></textarea>
  </form>
</div>
```

So, what's the way of doing this ?

Comment: You can't give a common class for all those links, detect the click event for the same & show the popup contents based on the id which is passed to the function?

Comment: As a side note, looks not what you are expecting here: `id="$id"`. You set ID to `$id`, not value regarding server side `$id` variable

Comment: @A.Wolff, $id means a PHP variable

Comment: @JensonMJohn Yes, popup will be triggered because of the onclick function. The content is based on the passing argument $id.

Comment: @TharinduLucky BUT in PHP `echo '<a href="#" id="$id" ...>'` whould output just `<a href="#" id="$id" ...>`. That's not hard to confirm what output do you get

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve contents from Server using AJAX for the id.

Try something like :

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI with Ajax</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".dialog").on("click", function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url: "content.php?id="+id,
            success: function(data){
                $("#dialog").html(data);
            }   
        });

        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
          }
        });

      });
   });

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="My Content">
  <!--Your Content-->
</div>

 <h2><a href="#" id="1" class="dialog">Link 1</a></h2>
 <h2><a href="#" id="2" class="dialog">Link 2</a></h2>
 <h2><a href="#" id="3" class="dialog">Link 3</a></h2>
 <h2><a href="#" id="4" class="dialog">Link 4</a></h2>
 <h2><a href="#" id="5" class="dialog">Link 5</a></h2>

</body>
</html>


Content.php

<?php

$id = $_REQUEST['id'];

echo "Data From the server for id ".$id;

?>
```